# Recuperar link gerado por um ajax

Tags: ajax

Bom dia galera.

Eu estou fazendo um envio de dados para o outro domínio, usando, ajax + php.
Só que preciso fazer esse link gerado abrir, pra eles poderem fazer o envio dos dados do site, por causa do captcha.

```
    $.ajax({
        url:    "webproxy.php?url=" + encodeURIComponent("http://ecoprintq.com/index.php/partnerApplication/create"),

    data:            "User_full_name:aaaaaaa&User_institution:sssss",

    crossDomain:true,
    type: "GET",
    timeout: 30000,
    dataType: "text", // "xml", "json"
    success: function(data) {


    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, ex) {
        alert(textStatus + "," + ex + "," + jqXHR.responseText);
    }
});
```

Esse ajax retorna:

```
jquery-1.10.2.js:7 XHR finished loading: GET "http://127.0.0.1/ecoLicenseLayout/webproxy.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Fecoprintq.c…FpartnerApplication%2Fcreate&User_full_name:aaaaaaa&User_institution:sssss".
send 
@ jquery-1.10.2.js:7ajax
 jquery-1.10.2.js:7(anonymous function) 
@ teste.php:44
```

Queria saber se tem alguma função para pegar o

"http://127.0.0.1/ecoLicenseLayout/webproxy.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Fecoprintq.c…FpartnerApplication%2Fcreate&User_full_name:aaaaaaa&User_institution:sssss"

Comment: Tenta dentro da função success: `console.log(data);` e vê o que dá

Comment: ele aparece todo o html

Comment: Ha como resposta ele recebe um html e tu gostavas de extrair esse link? Coloca o HTML relevante na pergunta, o que tem esse link, e explica também isto na pergunta. Vai a http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/171006/edit. Sê bem-vindo, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Cara, já estava editando ele, olha ai

Comment: O que é preciso ver é o HTML que disse que era enviado como resposta, e o link (`data`)

Comment: tu quer ver o html gerado?

Comment: Meu caro, o html que falo, é toda uma resposta., porém só da para vê-la no console.


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
    <head>        
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/477107c0/jui/css/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/assets/b0bfca91/mbmenu.css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/477107c0/jquery.js"></script>
...


Ele me retorna exatamente o código da página

Comment: Ok, esse e qual é o link desse html que quer extrair?

Comment: Não é bem desse html, é um html que envia para essa página, mas é gerada pelo ajax.
...
http://127.0.0.1/ecoLicenseLayout/webproxy.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Fecoprintq.com%2Findex.php%2FpartnerApplication%2Fcreate&User_full_name:aaaaaaa&User_institution:sssss

Isso que quero recuperar

Comment: Acho que percebi, já estou a responder

Comment: ok, obrigado meu caro

Comment: Gabriel, esse link gerado vem no meio do HTML (`data`) certo? Se sim, coloque esse HTML em vez do php na pergunta, e diga qual é o link no meio desse HTML que quer extrair

Comment: Não, não tem link no meio do html cara '-'

Eu preciso dar um jeito de pegar o html que é gerado pela requisição.

Comment: XHR finished loading: GET "http://127.0.0.1/ecoLicenseLayout/webproxy.php?url=http%3A%2F%2Fecoprintq.c…FpartnerApplication%2Fcreate&User_full_name:aaaaaaa&User_institution:sssss".

Tem esse link ai... preciso pegar esse link do localhost até o ssss, com o javascript, porém esse só aparece no console

Comment: sacaram o que preciso?

Comment: alguém pode ajudar?